# Getting error local variable XXXX referenced before assignment in Python 3.8

Tags: python

I am developing a web app using Angular 9 for frontend and Flask in python 3.8 for backend, everything was going well till i tried to connect the backend with the data base, where the code apparently its ok, flask start running succesfully but when i tried to use my endpoint for authentication, flask throws the error:

```
**local variable 'conn' referenced before assignment**
```

i have been checking some forums and so on but i dont understand what is going on. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import pymysql

database_name = "dbx80"
database_user = "user_auth"
database_password = "Jan2019@"


def conection_database(db):
    try:
        conn = (pymysql.connect(
            unix_socket="/cloudsql/servicisEX:us-central1:dbx43",
            port = 3306,
            user = database_user,
            password = database_password,
            database = database_name,  
            charset="utf8"
        ))

        print(f"Connection {database_name} Succesful")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to {database_name}")

    return conn
```

Comment: I think you need to put the return inside your try block, because it is called no matter what happens in the try except block. After `print(f"Connection {database_name} Succesful")` then `return conn`

Comment: add `conn = None` before `try` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comment to an answer.

`return conn` is called no matter the result of the try except block.

If you put the return statement inside the try block, the error will not occur.

Example:

```
import pymysql

database_name = "dbx80"
database_user = "user_auth"
database_password = "Jan2019@"


def conection_database(db):
    try:
        conn = (pymysql.connect(
            unix_socket="/cloudsql/servicisEX:us-central1:dbx43",
            port = 3306,
            user = database_user,
            password = database_password,
            database = database_name,  
            charset="utf8"
        ))

        print(f"Connection {database_name} Succesful")
        return conn

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to {database_name}")
```

Comment: i did that but now it says "module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'

Comment: That is a whole new problem then.